# Get Data of current route before redirecting to new route in angular 4

Tags: angular, routes, angular4-router

**Actual Requirement :**
Before redirecting to new route I want to trigger a function of current route(component). This function actually is for saving the values of the form present in current route.(Auto Save the data of current component before redirecting to new route(component)).

**My Solution:**
I will check the data of current route before redireting to new route that data will consists the name of current route name and function name to trigger.

**Challenge:**
How to get the data of current route before redirecting to the new route?

Below is sample code:

**routing.ts**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
          { path: 'overviewHistory', component: OverviewHistoryComponent,data: { state: 'overviewHistory',function:'abc' }},
          { path: 'leadDetails', component: LeadInformationComponent, data: { state: 'leadDetails',function:'abc1' } },
          { path: 'checeklist', component: CheckListComponent,data: { state: 'checeklist',function:'abc2' }},
          { path: 'teamManagement', component: TeamManagementProfileComponent,data: { state: 'teamManagement',function:'abc3' }},
          { path: 'directorDetails', component: DirectorOtherpartyDetailComponent,data: { state: 'directorDetails',function:'abc4' }},
          { path: 'addressDetails', component: AddressDetailsComponent,data: { state: 'addressDetails',function:'abc5' }},
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="site-content" class="content full-width" [@routerTransition]="getState(o)" >
        <router-outlet #o="outlet"  (activate)="optionChange(o)"></router-outlet>

</div>
```

**TS :**

```
  optionChange(outlet){
    // Some logic....
  }
```

Please help in achieve this objective. Also suggest if any new way to achieve the actual requirement.

Comment: have you checked with `this.router.events` ? into your component and call function on every router change

Comment: not a straight forward answer, but you can use `CanDeactivate` guard 
 and ask user permission for discarding the changes, if user says no you can work on saving and proceed.

Comment: Can you explain it ?? I am thinking to use ngOnDestroy() hook as I need to call the function from current component only.. Is this good way??

Comment: @RajeevRanjan... your solution seems more interesting can you pls explain your approach?

Comment: you can refer this link https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-candeactivate-guard-example and see whether it will for you or not ?

Comment: and here is a sample https://stackblitz.com/angular/omplpnlkrdx from angular documentation

Comment: Angular router destroys your child component (Default behavior when you don't have customized ReuseStrategy) when the route changes with the ngDestroy() hook, you can cleanup, store, update, unsubscribe etc. there

Comment: @RajeevRanjan... Thnx... Your answer is useful for now,,,But having a doubt...the same we can achieve by ngOnDestroy() hook as well than what is difference and which one is good....

Comment: @NishantVarshney, `ngOnDestroy` callback is typically used for any custom cleanup that needs to occur when the instance is destroyed.So I would go ahead with `CanDeactivate`.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan...Got your point.... I have one more requirement..how can we open the customize alert box for confirmation...right now it is simple JS alert...

Comment: @RajeevRanjan... Not working when i open any custom component as a alert...